# How to properly wrap server response to client

Tags: java, spring, rest

Task:

- Make a single wrapper for server responses to the client.

My decision:

- Create an ApiResponse object and use it in the controller and services
  Am I doing the right thing? Sorry I don't know much about this...

ApiResponce

```
@Data
public class ApiResponse {

    private Date timestamp;
    private int status;
    private String message;
    private Object data;

    public ApiResponse(int status, String message, Object data) {
        this.timestamp = new Date();
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
        this.data = data;
    }
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/admin")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
public class Admin {

    private final UserService userService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/users/add", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.addUser(user));
    }

}
```

Service

```
public interface UserService {

    ApiResponse addUser(User user);
    ApiResponse updateUser(User user);
    ApiResponse getUserByEmail(String email);
    ApiResponse getUserById(Long id);
}
```

Implementation method example

```
@Override
    public ApiResponse addUser(User user) {

        log.info("Saving new user to the database. Email: {}", user.getEmail());

        // Check if the user is already in the database
        User useDB = userRepo.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if (useDB != null) {
            return new ApiResponse(200, "A user with this e-mail already exists in the system!", user);
        }

        try {
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
            userRepo.save(user);
            return new ApiResponse(200, "User added successfully", null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("New user added error! " + ex.getMessage());
            return new ApiResponse(403, "New user registration error! " + ex.getMessage(), null);
        }
    }
```

Am I moving in the right direction? Or is it a sign of bad code?

Actually what I tried above)

Comment: Nice codes but why don't you just let controllers return ```ApiResponse```s.  Passing ```ApiResponse``` to ```ResponseEntity```'s wildcard is redundant because ```ApiResponse``` already has everything a response need. ```ResponesEntity```s are used for some primitive type like int/String or any other stateless info. Like when your service return **Jennifer**,then you should make it like ```name:Jennifer, info:my friend, code:200```, but the job already done by ```ApiResponse```.

Comment: Are you suggesting to do this and not use ResponseEntity?

public ApiResponse addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userService.addUser(user);
 }

Comment: Yes.If you just set the same code as HttpResponse code.

Comment: Very sound idea, thanks! I wouldn't use my wrapper at all if I could pass my message to the ResponseEntity and the status code, but I can only get the status code from the UserServiceImpl during request processing.

Comment: You're more than welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you're doing good. Make sure to use BCryptPasswordEncoder in Configuration file in order to make password encrypted.

Comment: There is such a @Bean, of course. Thank you!